# Copy out results after submitting web form using Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I am trying to use Selenium to (1) submit a query in a website, and then (2) copy out the contents of the result using beautiful soup. This is my script for the 1st part...

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Users\XXX\Scripts\MyPythonScripts\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get(r'http://www.ars-grin.gov/cgi-bin/npgs/html/tax_search.pl?language=en')

elem = browser.find_element_by_name('search')
elem.send_keys('Syzygium polyanthum')
elem.submit()
```

For the 2nd part, I realised that I have to somehow copy the new url of the result into a variable, before I can use beautiful soup to grab the contents, but I have no idea how to do that after googling extensively.

Does anyone know this, or any alternative methods to achieve the same result?

Comment: If you want to get the current url, `browser.current_url` Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to feed the page source to `BeautifulSoup` after submitting a form. If this is the case, use `browser.page_source`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source)
```

Comment: Wow thanks lots! This works perfectly. I'm sorry I can't rank the answer as useful as I am new to the forum (not enough reputation points), but will do so once I can!

Answer (score 2):

If your question is to get the current browser url then,

```
browser.current_url
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! alexce's script is better for me but this works too. I'm sorry I can't rank the answer as useful as I am new to the forum (not enough reputation points), but will do so once I can also!